# How can I debug a live contract on Testnet

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

I have posted a simple token contact on Ropsten and have a basic function to Buy tokens and now due to some error EVM is reverting the transaction ..

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xdafc102f2bf7a623034ae09d521f327ea6e9277076eaa7d7c98ba55994b880b5

I would like to debug the transaction and wnat to check out the run time states along with why it is fail in interacting way like we do other dubugging on Node etc..

Is there a good way to dubug and investigate the code.

Regards
Dev

Answer (score 0):

For debugging live contracts I recommend using remix.

https://remix.ethereum.org

Connect to ropsten using your metamask browser and load your contract.

Also remix has a debug mode.

Comment: is it also possible to perform same task using Truffle?

Comment: See https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-truffle-develop-and-the-console, but once a contract is deployed you can't really debug it live. I recommend migrating your contracts to either truffle console or ganache.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response .. let me try with the suggested methods .. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

it's a confuse question to a solidity developer. I think there has no way to debug a live contract already deployed on any testnet. remix offer a debug method to check the storage and memory varibles, but it need you to use remix-ide as evm. you can read their documents to learn how to debug. [remix debug tab](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugger_tab.html)